# ngx-mat-select-search covers my scrollbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I used ngx-mat-select-search in a component and under it, I have ngFor'd over several mat-options. The problem is that the ngx-mat-select-search covers part of my scrollbar. How, do I get around this? I'm not sure if or how I can override ngx-mat-select-search css styles in my components css

I tried, wrapping the ngx-mat-select-search in a separate div to control it's width, position. I tried to change width of the mat-select-panel in my css. nothing worked.

````
     <mat-option>
       <ngx-mat-select-search></ngx-mat-select-search>
     </mat-option>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let bank of ...">...</mat-option>
   </mat-select>```
````

Comment: can you post a screenshot? could you also create a stackblitz.com example?

Comment: there is a mechanism that should automatically adjust the width so that the scrollbar is not hidden (see https://github.com/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search/blob/8f1fbab4fb13fb77905e615ff81b8cc73f4468d3/src/app/mat-select-search/mat-select-search.component.ts#L538-L557), so it is strange that you experience this problem.
could you give more details in which setup this occurs?

Comment: in my test environment (Chrome, Windows), the issue you describe does not occur in the example https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example